# How can I keep the RHEL version static (e.g. RHEL 5.1)?

Tags: yum, redhat, update

For compatibility with a program :

- I need to keep one of our servers in a specific version, for example rhel 5.1
- I would like to keep it as updated as possible, but not to change versions.

What should I do:

Configure yum?
Configure satellite repository?

Comment: What specifically do you need to stay static for your application to work correctly?

Answer (score 11):

Do not update the package called redhat-release-5Server-

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/redhat-release
redhat-release-5Server-5.3.0.3
```

Make sure to pin that package. If you do edit /etc/yum.conf and put this in it

```
[main]
exclude=redhat-release-5Server-*
```

yum would refrain from updating that package and that would keep /etc/redhat-release at its current version.

Not sure why you would want this though...

Comment: Sheesh, Dennis, you are a spelling fanatic :-) And you already have the 'Strunk & White' badge :-D (joke, joke) Thanks for fixing the typo though...

Comment: Is this preventing updates coming after the pinned release? If not, I don't see the point.

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude either. You will get updates all updates within the minor version. The exclude directive excludes the specified packages from update. In this case the version of the OS will not be upgraded but it would still upgrade all packages within that release.

i.e. In your case after putting in the exclude line (You can put either version of exclude), the version of RHEL would stay at 5.6 but any upgrades within RHEL5.6 will be applied.

http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/yum_HOWTO/yum_HOWTO.txt