# yum update to specific kernel version

Tags: yum, rhel5, kernel

On rhel 5.3 I want to update to kernel version "2.6.18-128.8.1.el5" due to a security patch.
When performing:

```
yum check-update | grep kernel
kernel.x86_64                            2.6.18-164.2.1.el5     rhel-x86_64-server-5
kernel-devel.x86_64                      2.6.18-164.2.1.el5     rhel-x86_64-server-5
kernel-headers.x86_64                    2.6.18-164.2.1.el5     rhel-x86_64-server-5
```

But 2.6.18-164.2.1.el5 correspond to rhel 5.4, and I dont want to move to this version, I want to keep rhel 5.3.

I tried

```
yum update kernel-2.6.18-128.8.1
```

But it seems to be the wrong way.
How could I update the server to this specific kernel version?

Answer (score 6):

You are on the right track. You just didn't specify the kernel version the way yum expects it. The correct command would be

`yum install kernel-2.6.18-128.8.1.el5`

(Note that kernel packages are not updates for each other, each of them is a separate install, and the old ones remain until you run "rpm -e".)

Comment: I also tried that, but it says: "No Packages marked for Update".
I even tried including arch, but nothing.

Comment: If nothing else helps - log on to rhn.redhat.com and search for the correct package in your subscription channel. Then download and install manually.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try would be to freeze your redhat-release level, I'm not sure if this would prevent you from moving to a kernel newer than 2.6.18-128.8.1.el5, but it would prevent your release from being updated to 5.4

[How can I keep the RHEL version static (e.g. RHEL 5.1)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/70021/how-can-i-keep-the-rhel-version-static-e-g-rhel-5-1)
See answer by Dennis Williamson

Answer (score 0):

Install the yum-security plugin:

```
yum install yum-security
```

Then you can do:

```
yum --security update-minimal kernel
```

...along with a bunch of other features.