# Keep RHEL at a particular minor revision level?

Tags: redhat, rhel6, update

I'm working with a large database platform *(Or#&%@)* that requires a specific revision level of Red Hat Enterprise Linux. In this case, it needs EL6.2 in order to retain support and compatibility with several DB features that we intend to use.

What is the cleanest, most elegant way to update this system to the latest 6.2 revision with updates, without pulling the EL6.4 packages down?

I've seen: [How can I keep the RHEL version static (e.g. RHEL 5.1)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/70021/how-can-i-keep-the-rhel-version-static-e-g-rhel-5-1)

That approach did not work on the system in question.

This is a one-off, and I'd prefer to avoid [Cobbler](http://cobbler.github.com/about.html), [Satellite Server](http://www.redhat.com/products/enterprise-linux/rhn-satellite/), etc. Is there a way to handle this via config files or at the yum level?

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the base channel to 6.2 inside RHN or from the command line?

This should pin you to that minor release.

[image: screenshot of RHN showing Base Software Channel drop-down]

Comment: The "EUS" stands for [Extended Update Support](http://www.redhat.com/products/enterprise-linux-add-ons/extended-update-support/). Additional cost. It does not seem to be available to be as an option.